# Configure "Link-Local Only" without NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have two computers, each of which I want to connect to a camera that communicates via "Link-Local" Ethernet.

The first computer has a full install of 12.10. I can get the camera communicating by going to `NetworkManager -> Edit Connections -> Edit... -> IPv4 Settings -> Method -> Link-Local Only`. Visually this looks like:

[image]

This works great. However, the second computer is an install of 12.10-minimal and does not have the Network Manager or a GUI. To configure it manually via the command line I have tried this:

```
ifconfig eth0 169.254.7.43 broadcast 169.254.255.255 netmask 255.255.0.0
```

which is identical to the `ifconfig` produced on the first computer. However, the camera is not recognized.

**The big question:** How do I configure my Ethernet port like Network Manager's "Link-Local Only" without Network Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a different IP address for your second PC:

`ifconfig eth0 169.254.7.`**44**`broadcast 169.254.255.255 netmask 255.255.0.0`

Comment: This ended up working. It turns out that for every port on any computer, a different link-local address must be assigned. Do you know why this is? Why can I not assign the same IP from different ethernet devices, and have my camera be recognized?

Comment: IP address have to be unique for every device connected over the same physical network. Therefore you have to assign a different IP address for all your ethernet devices.

Comment: I am facing some problems using this method. The static address assigned keeps getting reset for some reason. do you have any clue on what might be causing this? I am on 12.04 desktop and my original question is [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/401064/temporary-static-ip-address)